# EmEditor Macro Error - 'document' is undefined

Tags: emeditor

I used EmEditor for years now. Now I want to create and use a simple macro.
But every time a run a macro I get the error message:

'document' is undefined

[image: 1]

I can fix the problem by deinstallation and a new installation of Emeditor.
But after a reboot, the same error will be show again.

I use EmEditor Professional 64-bit Version 22.2.0 on a Windows 10 22H2.

I had this issue also in the past, on a different notebook.
So this issue seems to be independend of my windows installion.

There is no third parts virus scanner installed, only windows defender.
EmEditor is installed in the standard path.

This error happens with the default marcos like ValidateXml.jsee or also with self recored and save macros.

Comment: This is a bug in EmEditor. Please contact us with the [contact form](https://www.emeditor.com/support/#contact) so that we will be able to file the bug and reply to you properly.

Comment: dear MakotoE-San , thank you for your replay. I will contact you via the form and file a bug report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run EmEditor as **Administrator**, please run EmEditor as **non-Admininistrator**. Please run `emeditor.exe` without a shortcut to see if macros run correctly.

Comment: Thank you, running EmEditor without Administrator-rights solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you can run macro's from clipboard?
Please try it for example with "alert(document.name)".
Put this between "" to clipboard and select in menu macros - run clipboard.
In normal case you get an popup with the actual document name.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried to run the command above with the command run clipboard from Marco menu. Result nothing happens. So this seems to be a bug in Emeditor.